# how can I check how much memory is allocated for my C program in memory when I run my program

Tags: c, memory

hey I want to check that how much memory is allocated for my C program in memory when i run because I want to reduce the size of my program if I get that how much memory used my program so then its help to me to reduce the size.
so any can tell me how can I do this in C ?

Comment: that would depend on the OS/environment

Comment: For linux you can try `size` command.

Comment: What `o/s` are you using?It is dependent on it.

Comment: Hey bro let suppose that I used 4 int variables and some further statements so suppose my file size is 200 bytes and after that I declared one more integer variable in the same program so my program size will have to be 204 but its just increment by 2 and so the according to you it shows size according to how many character I used but I want that when I run my program how much memory will allocate for my program ?

Comment: I doubt anyone here is your 'bro' :-)

Answer (score 5):

**On Windows:**

Right click on the `TaskBar` (Windows 7/ Windows 8) & `CTRL+ALT+DEL` on Windows XP, click Start `Task Mananger`. A windows will popup, go to `Performance tab` and click on `Resource Moniter` button. A new windows will pop up. Find your process there in the list of `Memory section`.

**On Linux:**

Get pid of the process and type `top -p PID`. It will display information about the process, including percent of system memory used.