# how can I check when i run my program how much memory is occupied by my program in memory

Tags: c, memory

I want to check that when i run my program how much memory is occupied by my program in memory because I want to reduce the size of my program if I get that how much memory occupy my program then its help to me to reduce the size. so any one can tell me how can I do this in C?

In detail, 
 lets suppose that I used 4 integer variables and some statements in our program and then I run my program on that time in memory how much memory reserved/ use by my program ?? Thats my main question.. and how chack I check that

Comment: this is OS specific, which OS are you running?

Comment: Asked 1h ago : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354203/how-can-i-check-how-much-memory-is-allocated-for-my-c-program-in-memory-when-i-r

Comment: Hey bro let suppose that I used 4 int variables and some further statements so suppose my file size is 200 bytes and after that I declared one more integer variable in the same program so my program size will have to be 204 but its just increment by 2 and so the according to you it shows size according to how many character I used but I want that when I run my program how much memory will allocate for my program ?

Comment: @VikasVerma You could edit your question and put that stuff in in a readable form.

Comment: Ohk lets suppose that I used 4 integer variables and some statements in our program and then I run my program on that time in memory how much memory reserved/ use by my program ?? Thats my main question.. and how chack I check that